# Flutter Pie Chart charts_flutter label not visible correctly

Tags: flutter, charts

I am using flutter charts_flutter and I am having an issue about label, it isn't shown.
Any solution that I can make it show please?

[image for issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC1Dx.png)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can solve your problem from this example
https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/issues/60

Comment: Thank you! I have searched this already and this is using different package.
Let me try other packages.

Comment: ohh ok, you are welcome